How do I get the Balance Data from Stripe - Connected Accounts?
I am trying to access the Stripe API account but was not able to retrieve the Balance data, I need the endpoint to get it
I am using the https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts/acct_1NfnzBHIBayKCYf4 endpoint but the Balance and other fields are not fetched.
API Endpoint and the parameters needed
enter image description here

Here's the guide on how you retrieve the balance on the connected account: https://docs.stripe.com/connect/account-balances#check-connected-account-balance
For example using Balance Retrieval API,
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance \
  -u "sk_123:" \
  -H "Stripe-Account: {{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}"

